# How to disable backward slash separator for one subfolder in VS Code file explorer?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using Visual Studio Code (VS Code) and I have noticed that when I create a subfolder within a folder, it is represented with a backward
slash () separator in the file explorer. While I understand that this is the standard convention for Windows-based operating systems, I find it difficult to read and it takes up a lot of space.

[image]

Is there any way to disable the backward slash separator for one subfolder in the file explorer of VS Code, as I can recall it was not in the VSCode 1/2 years back?

Comment: Does turning off the compact folders options for explorer suffice?

Comment: @TimothyG. yes, from the settings `Compact Folders` turning off solved the issue. Thanks.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Thanks, that link answer also related to my question.